# What are the similarities and differences between dependent function application and ML functor application?

Tags: type-theory, functional-programming

Advanced Topics in Types and Programming Languages gives this rule  section 2.2 gives this rule for dependent function application:

$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash t_1 : (\Pi x : S.T) \quad \Gamma \vdash t_2 : S}{\Gamma \vdash t_1 t_2  : [ x \mapsto t_2 ] }$$

In ["Modules Matter Most"](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/modules-matter-most/) Bob Harper gives this rule for ML functor application:

$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash M : A \quad \Gamma, x : A \vdash N : B}{\Gamma \vdash [M / x ] N : B}$$

What are the similarities and differences between these judgments?

To give a concrete example of the kind of thing I'm looking for, I asked ChatGPT to compare the rules and it said (among other things):

1. In the ML functor application rule, the argument $N$ is an expression that depends on $x$, whereas in the dependent function application rule, the argument $t_2$ is a simple value of type $S$.
2. In the ML functor application rule, the result type $B$ does not depend on the value of the argument $M$, whereas in the dependent function application rule, the return type $T$ depends on the value of the argument $t_2$.

I suspect that the ChatGPT answer is misleading.

Comment: ChatGPT isn't really good with academics, and often gives believable but incorrect results - so I really recommend against asking it such questions :o

Comment: The harm is in believing